# Laravel queue listener and daemon quit after one job

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

When I run 'php artisan queue:listen' or 'php artisan queue:work --daemon' it processes one job then quits and throws this exception:

```
[2014-09-18 10:36:37] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'The "-e" option does not exist.' in /var/www/api/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php:128
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/api/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php(109): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parseShortOptionSet()
#1 /var/www/api/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php(88): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parseShortOption()
#2 /var/www/api/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/Input.php(61): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parse()
#3 /var/www/api/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(234): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input->bind()
#4 /var/www/api/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(100): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#5 /var/www/api/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(889): Illuminate\Console\Command->run()
#6 /var/www/api/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(193): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#7 /var/www/api/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#8 /var/www/api/public_html/artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#9 {main} [] []
```

I'm running laravel 4.2.8 and I use redis queue

Comment: Just to make sure. queue:listen listen for jobs and has a default timeout of 60 secounds. You can change that with the --timeout=0 flag. queue:work just grabs one job from the queue. Check your code that gets executed. Looks like you call some command line program with a parameter that does't exists

Comment: I don't get a timeout exception so I don't think changing the time out will be useful, queue:work takes 1 job, but queue:work --daemon runs and grabs jobs until stopped. The code executed is a simple GET request using guzzle, no command line programs.

Comment: Didn't know there was a deamon flag, now you helped me. Thanks mate

Comment: Read this before you use it:
http://laravel.com/docs/queues#daemon-queue-worker